# Evil inclination compared to a strange god within man

Tags: commentaries, avodah-zarah, evil-inclination

I've found [this](http://www.kabbalah.info/eng/content/view/frame/32165?/eng/content/view/full/32165&main) article which quoted some interesting thoughts:

> Our sages said about the verse (Shabbat 105b), “*There shall not be a strange god within you, nor will you bow before a strange god*.”
>
> What is the strange god in man’s body? It is the evil inclination. This means that an idol-worshipper is called “the evil inclination.” It follows that when speaking of a single body, then idol-worshipping, which is called “a foreign god” or “a strange god,” is entirely within man.

So here are my questions:
Why is the evil inclination compared to a foreign/strange god?

Also, what is the connection between idolatry and the evil inclination?

And why is it assumed that both come from or occur within man?

Comment: The evil inclination tells you that G-d is not everything. You can get satisfaction even if you disobey G-d's Will. There is an alternative to G-d. Now, isn't that avodah zarah mamash?

Comment: First, the phrase is interpreted allegorically, originally בך (within you) means the whole Jewish nation (you all), not a single person.

Comment: Look at the original Targum of that Pasuk (Psalms 81): לָא יְהֵי בֵינֵיכוֹן פָּלְחֵי טָעֲוָתָא נוּכְרָאָה וְלָא תִסְגְדוּן לְטַעֲוַת חִילוֹנָי: it says Ya all.

Comment: the word אל in that Pasuk is לשון חול not holy, "god" should be used in English.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303