# Does Judaism use darkness and light as a metaphor for good and evil?

Tags: lighting

Many religions contrast dark and light with good and evil.  Namely Christianity as a off shoot religion does exactly this in the new testament.

Does Judaism use these metaphors directly in any verses or are interpreted that way?

Comment: Reminder to VTCers that comparative religion questions require knowledge of other religions. This question, as it currently stands, does not, and therefore should be left open.

Comment: I don't know if this would be considered a metaphor but *Or Zaru'a Latzadik..." - "Lightness is planted for the righteous"? Psalms (I think it's in the 90's.)

Comment: See 1 Samuel 2:9, Job 30:26, Isaiah 5:20, 45:7, Psalm 4:6, 118:27, Proverbs 4:19.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Darkness and light are precursors in the six days of Creation. They arise on the first day.

For related discussion on the source of *Good* and *Evil*, see the following answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303

Answer (score 1):

Another one that strongly implies it would be [Isaiah 45:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.45.7?lang=bi):

> יוֹצֵ֥ר אוֹר֙ וּבוֹרֵ֣א חֹ֔שֶׁךְ עֹשֶׂ֥ה שָׁל֖וֹם וּב֣וֹרֵא רָ֑ע אֲנִ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה עֹשֶׂ֥ה כׇל־אֵֽלֶּה

> Fashioning light and creating darkness; making peace and creating evil -- I am God, Who does all these things.

A version of that actually appears in the daily prayers -- it blesses God "who fashions light and creates darkness, makes peace and creates **everything.**"

The deliberate shift from "evil" to "everything" was most likely a result of the prayer being formalized during the time of Zoroastrianism or a similar religion that saw, essentially, two different deities for good vs. evil. Hence Judaism stressed that evil just another part of "everything", ultimately controlled by one God.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's an example:

רַבִּי אַבָּהוּ וְרַבִּי חִיָּא רַבָּה, רַבִּי אַבָּהוּ אָמַר מִתְּחִלַּת בְּרִיָּתוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם צָפָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים וּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל רְשָׁעִים, הֲדָא הוּא דִּכְתִיב (תהלים א, ו): כִּי יוֹדֵעַ ה' דֶּרֶךְ צַדִּיקִים וְדֶרֶךְ רְשָׁעִים תֹּאבֵד. **וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ, אֵלּוּ מַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל רְשָׁעִים**, וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים **יְהִי אוֹר, אֵלּוּ מַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים**, אֲבָל אֵינִי יוֹדֵעַ בְּאֵיזֶה מֵהֶם חָפֵץ, אִם בְּמַעֲשֵׂה אֵלּוּ אִם בְּמַעֲשֵׂה אֵלּוּ, כֵּיוָן דִּכְתִיב וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים **אֶת הָאוֹר כִּי טוֹב**, הֱוֵי בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים חָפֵץ, וְאֵינוֹ חָפֵץ בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶן שֶׁל רְשָׁעִים. (בראשית רבה ב:ה)