# Why is the Evil Inclination Called a “fire”

Tags: sources-mekorot, evil-inclination, fire-burning, chofetz-chaim

In the [introduction of Chomat Hadat](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41647&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=), the Chofetz Chaim calls Yetzer Harah a "fire".

Why this comparison? What that means? And where is his source for this?

Comment: This is the concept that the Yetzer HaRah actually arises from G-d’s name and G-d is called a Consuming Fire. For related discussion, see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Kiddushin 81a ([Sefaria Translation](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.81a?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)):

> כי מטא לפלגא דרגא איפשח רמא קלא נורא בי עמרם אתו רבנן אמרו ליה כסיפתינן אמר להו מוטב תיכספו בי עמרם בעלמא הדין ולא תיכספו מיניה לעלמא דאתי אשבעיה דינפק מיניה נפק מיניה כי עמודא דנורא אמר ליה חזי דאת נורא ואנא בישרא ואנא עדיפנא מינך
>
> When he was halfway up the ladder, he strengthened his legs against the sides of the ladder to stop himself from climbing further, raised his voice, and cried out: There is a fire in the house of Amram. Upon hearing this, the Sages came and found him in that position. They said to him: You have embarrassed us, since everyone sees what you had intended to do. Rav Amram said to them: It is better that you be shamed in Amram’s house in this world, and not be ashamed of him in the World-to-Come. He took an oath that his evil inclination should emerge from him, and an apparition similar to a pillar of fire emerged from him. He said to his evil inclination: See, as you are fire and I am mere flesh, and yet, I am still superior to you, as I was able to overcome you.